# Програмно изменить цвет ProgressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-drawable

Нужно динамически менять цвет горизонтального ProgressBar, в зависимости от значения прогресса. Сделал так:

```
progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Цвет меняется.

Не нравится, что ProgressBar слишком узкий, атрибуты android:layout_height и android:minHeight не помогают. Сделал свой drawable для ProgressBar

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
        <size android:height="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated">
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_horizontal">
    <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated">
            <size android:height="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
```

Внешний вид теперь устраивает, но при смене цвета (как описано выше) весь ProgressBar заливается цветом.

Вопрос. Как сделать потолще стандартный ProgressBar или раскрасить кастомный?

Comment: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/android-change-progressbar-height/

Comment: По ссылке советуют тоже самое, что свой drawable. При progressbar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN) весь прогресс бар заливается цветом.